# how to merge register.php to html

Tags: php, database, html

I'm trying to create a user system for my website. So I successfully made a register.php.

```
<?php
// dbConfig.php is a file that contains your
// database connection information. This
// tutorial assumes a connection is made from
// this existing file.
include ("dbConfig.php");
//Input vaildation and the dbase code
if ( $_GET["op"] == "reg" )
 {
 $bInputFlag = false;
 foreach ( $_POST as $field )
  {
  if ($field == "")
   {
   $bInputFlag = false;
   }
  else
   {
   $bInputFlag = true;
   }
  }
 // If we had problems with the input, exit with error
 if ($bInputFlag == false)
  {
  die( "Problem with your registration info. "
   ."Please go back and try again.");
  }
 // Fields are clear, add user to database
 //  Setup query
 $q = "INSERT INTO `umass` (`email`,`password`,`school`) "
  ."VALUES ('".$_POST["email"]."', "
  ."PASSWORD('".$_POST["password"]."'), "
  ."'".$_POST["school"]."')";
 //  Run query
 $r = mysql_query($q);

 // Make sure query inserted user successfully
 if ( !mysql_insert_id() )
  {
  die("Error: User not added to database.");
  }
 else
  {
  // Redirect to thank you page.
  Header("Location: register.php?op=thanks");
  }
 } // end if
//The thank you page
elseif ( $_GET["op"] == "thanks" )
 {
 echo "<h2>Thanks for registering!</h2>";
 }

//The web form for input ability
else
 {
 echo "<form action=\"?op=reg\" method=\"POST\">\n";
 echo "Email Address: <input name=\"email\" MAXLENGTH=\"30\"><br />\n";
 echo "Password: <input type=\"password\" name=\"password\" MAXLENGTH=\"16\"><br />\n";
 echo "School: <input name=\"school\" MAXLENGTH=\"30\"><br />\n";
 echo "<input type=\"submit\">\n";
 echo "</form>\n";
 }
// EOF
?>
```

It works. When i try to migrate my code to my html
i receive this error.

```
die("Error: User not added to database.");
```

HTML CODE

```
<div id="register">
register.php code here
</div>
```

PS I edited my htaccess to run php script with html extension.

Thank You

Comment: your situation is not clear...

Comment: Please check the path of dbConfig.php file after including register.php into your html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change html file to php and:
try this

```
<div id="register">
   <?php include_once('register.php')?>
</div>
```